# recursive print field name in case class via shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

i have the next code:

```
trait X
case class Bar(id: Int) extends X
case class Foo(id: Int, bar: Bar) extends X
```

i want to print all field for `Foo` with inner classes, i use shapeless for it, and create poly:

```
object print1 extends Poly1 {
  implicit def c[K, V](
    implicit wk: Witness.Aux[K]) = {
     at[FieldType[K, V]](field => {
      wk.value
    })
  }
}

val foo = Foo(1, Bar(10))
val fooLgen = LabeledGeneric[Foo]
pritnln(fooLgen.to(foo).map(print1)) // => 'id::'bar
```

But How to print with internal classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you create an `HList` of keys and then print it. You can do it recursively as follows:

```
trait LowerPriorityPrint1 extends Poly1 {
  implicit def c[K, V](implicit wk: Witness.Aux[K]) = {
    at[FieldType[K, V]](field => {
      wk.value
    })
  }
}

object print1 extends LowerPriorityPrint1 {
   implicit def csub[K, V, L <: HList](
     implicit l : LabelledGeneric.Aux[V, L],
               mapper : Mapper[print1.type, L]
              ) = {
    at[FieldType[K, V]](field => {
      l.to(field).map(print1)
    })
  }
}

val foo = Foo(1, Bar(10))
val fooLgen = LabelledGeneric[Foo]
println(fooLgen.to(foo).map(print1)) // => 'idFoo :: 'idBar :: HNil :: HNil
```

shapeless works at compile time, so you have to create recursion at the type level, using implicits. `c` and `cSub` exist at the same time for the same key, you can decide which one is resolved first by declaring the one with lower priority in a supertrait

Comment: how shapeless understand which a method should be used for? and why impossible to use LabeledGeneric with original `c` method ?

Comment: shapeless works at compile time, so you have to create recursion at the type level, using implicits. `c` and `cSub` exist at the same time for the same key, you can decide which one is resolved first by declaring the one with lower priority in a supertrait. Look for the scala implicit resolution rules